# mod_rewrite redirect to clean URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite in my .htaccess to create the following clean URLs.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^groups$ /groups.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^personalise$ /personalise.php [L]
RewriteRule ^terms$ /terms.php [L]
```

All works well however I've been trying to get the original links to redirect to the smooth links. For example, if someone visits `www.mydomain.com` they'll be redirected to `www.mydomain.com/home` and likewise if they trail the domain with index.php or any other page name.

I've had a look at a few different rules that don't seem to work, I'm not very familiar with the module. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just put redirects in the pages themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving you 2 of these new rules:

1. To redirect `index.php` to `/home`
2. To remove `.php` extension

Your full .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /home [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^home$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^groups$ /groups.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^personalise$ /personalise.php [L]
RewriteRule ^terms$ /terms.php [L]
```